# Import fortawesome:fontawesome package with Meteor and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, font-awesome

I've installed the fortawesome (from fontawesome) of atmosphere by using the following command:

```
meteor add fortawesome:fontawesome
```

Do I have to declare/import it inside my scss main file/js files or can I just get going from here. Because I've just gone and started using it but no output.

```
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-5x"></i>
```

Do I need to import it; because I'm using react with meteor, into my js files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this isn't working is you are using the word `class`

You need to change it to `className` because you are using React.

When you are developing with React I recommend you open the JavaScript console as you will see errors like that in there!